# printing results of solution of a genetic algorithm

Tags: python, function, genetic-algorithm

I am setting up this function, which needs inputs of other functions to be executed. Here is my code:

I want to run print_function(genetic_solution)

```
def print_function(solution):       # why is my function not changing parameters ????
  
  workerOrderArray(solution)    #returns R1, R2, R3
  
  workerOrderDaysarray(R1, R2, R3) #returns R1_days, R2_days, R3_days
  
  assignSchedule(R1, R1_days)    #returns R1_schedule
  assignSchedule(R2, R2_days)     #returns R2_schedule
  assignSchedule(R3, R3_days)    #returns R3_schedule
  
  schedules= [R1_schedule, R2_schedule, R3_schedule]

  for i in schedules:
    print(i)

  return
```

now the "genetic solution" is the solution i get from a genetic algorithm which is lengthy to define here. But should be a different solution than initially defined.. The initial solution defined is called "solution"

each function inside saves a global variable and that variable is input to next function...

Now what i dont understand is this: This function seems to use initial value of all parameters (from "solution" and not the new values returned from the "genetic_solution").

Is there something I am missing in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: "each function inside saves a global variable and that variable is input to next function..." No! Don't do this! This is the definition of Spaghetti code. Instead `return` the result from a function and assign the return value to **local** variables. Then use these local variables as input to the next function

Comment: and how do i assign the return to a local variable?

Comment: `R1, R2, R3 = workerOrderArray(solution)` assuming your workerOrderArray function was retruning a tuple of the 3 values

Comment: actually R1, R2, & R3 are 3 lists, in this case how do i assign each to a local variable?

Comment: i returned a list of [R1,R2,R3] and defined local variables as a=workerOrderArray(solution)[0], b= a=workerOrderArray(solution)[1], c=workerOrderArray(solution)[2], is there a better way to do it?